# Trying to adjust the width for a select option tag using Bootstrap with Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
%h2=@activity.title
=form_for @time_tracker do |f|
    .text
        =f.label :clock_in
        =f.datetime_select :clock_in
    .text
        =f.label :clock_out
        =f.datetime_select :clock_out
    .btn.btn-primary
        =f.submit "#{text}"
```

The select is too wide for my needs as you can see in the picture below. How can I change the default width value for option tags in Bootstrap?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a class within your `.css` file:

```
.option-large {
  width: 120px !important;
}
```

Use it on your inputs:

```
=f.datetime_select :clock_in, :class => 'option-large'
```

EDIT:

I think there is an aditional hash to the syntax, but i am not sure.

```
=f.datetime_select :clock_in, {}, {:class => 'option-large'}
```

Comment: I am trying to figure that out. It doesn't want to take the class. And if it takes it would it go on the select tag or on the option tag? The first syntax is right but I don't think it works the same for this select tag...